# Converting PDF doc to image as preserving the PDF quality at image?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, conversion, jpeg

I have looked to the site and find `convert` like programs and used them however I cannot preserve the quality of the PDF file. I have changes the options for better resolutions but this time the size was increased so much. I cannot find the optimal setting for the conversion. Is there any other tool or method to preserve the pdf quality? Or any program to see the specs of the PDF files to define them as argument of the conversion software?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1) You should be able to adjust the **image quality** by adding **density option** to the **convert** command as in this **Nautilus Script** which converts the selected PDF file to 300dpi JPG file(s)

`convert -density 300 "$1" "${1%\.pdf}.jpg"`

2) You can also open a PDF file with **GIMP Image Editor** (treating each page as a **Layer** or **Image**) which seems to use the PDF file settings as default as well as allowing the user to adjust the image quality setting at the beginning. Then you can **Export** it to any other image format.